# How do I get 2 sums on 2 conditions in 1 SQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table as illustrated below. How do I SELECT SUM column price WHERE type=1 AND type=2? I want the total of the price where type=1 and the total of the price where type=2 in just one query.

```
+-----+------+-------+
| PID | Type | Price |
+-----+------+-------+
|   1 |    1 |   100 |
|   2 |    2 |    65 |
|   3 |    1 |   300 |
|   4 |    1 |   200 |
|   5 |    2 |    50 |
+-----+------+-------+
```

I have tried this but it returns an error:

```
$this->db->select("SUM(price) as total1, (SELECT SUM(price) where type=2) as total2");
$this->db->from('table');
$this->db->where('type', '1');
$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result();
```

I have also tried a few other ways of writing my query but to no avail, and all other ways I found in SO are too complicated and too much for my simple query. I think this should be a very simple query.

Comment: what is the result of your current query ?

Comment: this query returns correct calc `select SUM(price) as total1, (SELECT SUM(price) from stack where type=2) as total2 from stack where type = 1`

Comment: @RahulSharma It return error "You have an error in your SQL syntax"

Comment: @RahulSharma my actual query, following your solution: $this->db->select("SUM(transaction_disc) as total1, (SELECT SUM(transaction_disc) from transaction where transaction_type=2) as total2 from transaction where transaction_type=1");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$this->db->select("SUM(price) as total1, (SELECT SUM(price) from table where type=2) as total2");
$this->db->from('table');
$this->db->where('type', '1');
$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result();
```

Comment: Thanks mate! exactly what I'm looking for

Answer (score 3):

```
$sql=select price from table where type=1";
$exesql=mysqli_query($sql) or die(mysqli_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($exesql)){
$tpeOneprice=$tpeOneprice+$row['price'];


}
echo $tpeOneprice;
```

do this to the type 2 also just like this.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you your two totals:

```
SELECT
    SUM(IF(type=1,price,0)) AS Total1,
    SUM(IF(type=2,price,0)) AS Total2
FROM table
WHERE type in (1,2)
```

Comment: this does return correct total but in 2 rows, i was expecting like total1 and total2 in one row, and there are other type that I do not want to be calculated, just type 1 and type 2.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion **`group by`** is best option(**options 2**) for your requirement.

**Option 1 :**

```
$query = $this->db->query("select SUM(CASE WHEN type= '1' then 1 else 0 end) as total1, SUM(CASE WHEN type= '2' then 1 else 0 end) as total2 from table");
$result = $query->result();
```

**PS:** You can also use group by on **type** column.

**With Group By (Option 2) :**

```
$this->db->select("SUM(type)");
$this->db->from('table');
$this->db->group_by('type');
$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result();
```

Comment: Both methods return the result in two rows, I was expecting the result to return in one row such as array[0]('total1' => 500, 'total2' => 1000)

Comment: it's single row with two columns, only group by returns two rows here.

Comment: @Charas your accepted answer and my given answer both return same data in same format. (Just pointing cause you mentioned it is not returning in correct format). BTW, cheers you got solution for you answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

I just tried in mysql.

Try this:

```
SELECT type, SUM(price) FROM test GROUP BY type
```

Comment: Yes this does work but the result return two rows, I am expecting the result to only return one row, like (array('total1' => 500, 'total2' => 250))